# python regular expressions to return complete result

Tags: python, regex

How can I get what was matched from a python regular expression?

```
re.match("^\\\w*", "/welcome")
```

All python returns is a valid match; but I want the entire result returned; how do I do that?

Comment: This expression should return `None`. Slash and backslash are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `re.findall` function.

```
>>> re.findall("a+", 'sdaaddaa')
['aa', 'aa']
```

Comment: I tried that but nothing valid is returned (and I'm using RegexBuddy to verify)

Comment: @nobody: That's because that pattern doesn't match that string.

Comment: @Roman Bodnarchuk that explains it; had it reversed and thanks for the findall

Answer (score 0):

You could use a group.

```
res = re.search("^(\\\w*)", "/welcome")
if res:
    res.group(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the [`group()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) method of the returned match object without any arguments will return the matched portion of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `"^\\\w*"` will match a string beginning with a backslash followed by 0 or more `w` characters. The string you are searching begins with a forward slash so your regex won't match. That's why you aren't getting anything back.

Note that your regex, if you printed out the string contains `\\w`. The `\\` means match a single backslash then the `w` means match a literal `w`. If you want a backslash followed by a word character then you will need to escape the first backslash and the easiest way would be to use a raw string `r"^\\\w*"` would match `"\\welcome"` but still not match `"/welcome"`.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you're "^" says you're string has to start at the beginning of a line. RegexBuddy doesn't tell that to you by default.
Maybe you want to tell us what exactly are you trying to find?